# Check abnormal connection drop before writing

Tags: tcl

I am new to TCL scripting and writing a production code to open a socket to our server and write command and then read its output. Below is my code:

```
set chan [socket 123.345.45.33 23]
fconfigure $chan -buffering line
foreach item [dict keys $command] { 
    set cmd [dict get $command $item]
    set res [Data_write $chan "get data $cmd"]  
}
```

Where Data_write procedure is mentioned below:

```
proc Data_write { channel data } {
    if {[eof $channel]} {
        close $channel
        ST_puts "Data_write: Error while writing to chanel"
        return -1
    } else {
        puts $channel $data
        return 0
    }
}
```

I am not sure that how can we achive the validations below:

> 1. set chan [socket 123.345.45.33 23] - socket connection open is success
> 2. fconfigure on the channel is success
> 3. How to know before any write that any abnormal connection drop has happen on channel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. `set chan [socket 123.345.45.33 23]` - socket connection open is success
> 2. `fconfigure` on the channel is success

These are simple enough: if there's a failure, you get a Tcl error, which is a sort of exception. You can use `catch` or `try` to trap the error if you want:

```
try {
    set chan [socket 123.345.45.33 23]
    fconfigure $chan -buffering line
} on error msg {
    puts "a serious problem happened: $msg"
    # Maybe also exit here...
}
```

> 3. How to know before any write that any abnormal connection drop has happen on channel?

The bad news is that you *can't* know this. The OS itself won't really know this until you do one of two things: write to the channel, or read from the channel. (There are *sometimes* hints available, such as `fileevent` events firing, but they're not certain at all.) Instead, you need to trap the error when actually you do the write. See above for the general pattern.

Remember: Tcl operations throw errors when they fail, and EOF is *not* an error when reading, but is an error when writing.

Answer (score 1):

Use `socket -async` and the readable and writeable fileevents to make the whole connection process event oriented.

In the writable event you can check the status of the connection using `fconfigure $channel -error`. If something failed in the connection, the socket is made writable and the error condition presented on the error property. If this is empty then you can configure the readable event and start processing data from the socket. In any readable event handler you should check for eof after reading and disable the readable event handler or close the socket once eof is seen as a socket in eof state becomes constantly readable.

This roughly works out to be:

```
proc OnWritable {chan} {
   set err [fconfigure $chan -error]
   if {$err ne "" } {
       puts stderr "ERROR: $err"
       exit 1
   }
   fconfigure $chan -blocking 0 -buffering none -encoding binary -translation lf
   fileevent $chan writable {}
   fileevent $chan readable [list OnReadable $chan]
}

proc OnReadable {chan} {
    set data [read $chan]
    puts "[string length $data]: $data"
    if {[eof $chan]} {
        fileevent $chan readable {}
        puts "closed $chan"
        set ::forever "closed"
    }
}

set sock [socket -async $address $port]
fileevent $sock writable [list OnWriteable $sock]
vwait ::forever
```

Comment: Thanls but I need to write command and get its value - so I cannot wait - I need to open the connection - check that connection is valid (no abnormal activity happened) and then read the output of the command written

Comment: I have multpile write command on the socket that needs to written and after each write I need to validate output via read

Comment: But opening a socket takes time…

Comment: That's not an issue - once socket is open I need to complete all execution of commands